# push notification- why i dint receive notification in device when the app in live

Tags: ios, notifications

can you help me anyone.

Actually,i develop a app with push notifications services.during the development process used devices are not receive any notification after distribution(when the app in live).i have installed both certificates as well in xcode. even though i dint receive any notification.

thanx in advance

Comment: did you confirm if the generated .pem and .p12 and all other certificates are correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

There is two possibility for not reserved Push Notification after app live:

**1: WRONG PEM FILE**

You need to replace development `PEM` to Distribution `PEM` file at you backed Server.

For the create a PEM file you need to export your distribution.cer and create PEM by following steps that suggest in the link:

https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Last line : cat `apns-dev-cert.pem apns-dev-key-noenc.pem > apns-dev.pem` in the above link there is mistake.

**2: REMOVE SANDBOX MODE**

After app live you need to remove sandbox word from the script

`gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`  to `gateway.push.apple.com:2195`